# Как на Ubunbtu поставить Notepad++?

Tags: ubuntu

У меня в Ubuntu возникла задача поиска по папкам. Для поиска в папках я использовал раньше notepad++.
Как произвести подобную операцию в Ubuntu при помощи редакторов или же установить notepad++?

Comment: а mc не пробовали использовать? там из коробки есть эти опции поиска.

Comment: это же не *ms/windows*. тут подобные задачи решаются гораздо проще. рекурсивный поиск имён файлов, содержащих искомую строку: `$ grep -lr 'искомая строка' путь/к/каталогу`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install notepadqq

должно быть так